# SimpleDateFormat.parse returns errorIndex as 0

Tags: java, java-7, simpledateformat, java-6

Using jdk1.7.0_55, I'm getting parseposition.errorIndex as 0 in case of timezone is not standard one.

But using jdk1.6.0_38 I'm getting parseposition.errorIndex as 21 for the same wrong timezone format

Below is the sample:

```
String date = "13 Jan 2005 21:45:34 ABC";
String format = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
pp.setIndex(0);
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = sd.parse(date,pp);
System.out.println("Error Index "+pp.getErrorIndex());
```

Result Using jdk 6:

> Error Index 21

Result Using jdk 7

> Error Index 0

Why there is difference in it?

Please help

Comment: I can reproduce it. Obviously a regression. You could send this message as bug to OpenJDK.

Comment: There shouldn't be but it seems like jdk 6 is giving you date and 7 is giving you pp.

Comment: Both will throw exception if I use parse(date) method. In jdk 6 it gives error index as correct position and in jdk 7 error index as 0. @TaylorCourtney

Answer (score 3):

Indeed this is a regression. Still broken in latest Java 8 build. Public OpenJDK bug tracker does not list it, so I have reported it to Oracle for review. It is tracked by Oracle with Review ID: JI-9021556

Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it is an answer. The answer is: it is a regression in the JDK.

Comment: This comment is automatically inserted during review. I'm not about to argue about the subtle difference between "looks like a..." and "is a...", but maybe you could extend the answer with credible information, e.g. a link to your bug report.

Comment: thanks for nitpicking, i changed the wording of the answer. Also i will update the answer as soon as I receive back the bug ID from oracle. however only parts of their bugtracker are public.

Comment: Have to agree it's not an answer. Answers should provide solutions (if any) not confirmations of the problem.

Comment: @holodec But this is saying that there is no solution, which is an answer.

Comment: @FabianLange  Can you please share the bug tracker link for this

Comment: I am sorry, but Oracle has not yet publicly documented the issue. As written in the answer this is handled by oracle using the review ID JI-9021556. You need to contact Oracle using your support contract to inquiry about it. I know it sucks, but thats how Oracle works.